# Android - Passing an Array of Classes Between Activities

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have three different Classes or Activities in an array. Each Class represents a puzzle. I have a function that rearranges the array at the start of the app so that the user won't see the same puzzle every time when they begin the app.

I want to pass this array of Classes from activity to activity. I am able to set the array to get passed but have no idea how to retrieve it in the following activity.

Here is the set up in Activity One

```
Class[] array = {PuzzleOne.class, PuzzleTwo.class, PuzzleThree.class};
Intent goToPuzzleOne = new Intent(MainActivity.this, array[0]);
goToPuzzleOne.putExtra("classes",array);
```

How do I retrieve this class in Activity Two?
Here's what I have so far

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 Class[] array = extras.NO IDEA HOW TO RETRIEVE IT HERE
```

Please let me know if there is a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we're dealing with a Map, you should go with:

```
Object[] array = (Object[]) extras.get("classes"); // you cannot cast to Class[] !
```

and then:

```
Class a = (Class) array[0]; // and etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look what the type of the second parameter of `putExtra("classes", array)` is, which turns out to be a `Serializable`.

Therefore you can get it back with `getSerializable()` and cast it to your Class array:

```
Class[] array = (Class[]) extras.getSerializable("classes");
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great! I haven't dealt much with serialization in the past, and although this works, I'm not exactly sure why? What does it mean for a class to be serialized? Is serialization primarily used for classes? Thank you, understanding the code helps me tremendously. I appreciate it!