# How can I pass an ArrayList of Strings between a Class and an Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a problem with passing an `ArrayList<String>`between `Class` and `Activity`.
I know I can use `Intent` for passing an array between `Activities` but I don't know how to do this with `Class` and `Activities`. Please help

this is my class

```
public class MultipleChoiceDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements Serializable {



    public interface onMultiChoiceListener{
        void onPositiveButtonClicked(String[] list , ArrayList<String> selectedItemList);
        void  onNegativeButtonClicked()
;
    }

    onMultiChoiceListener mlistner;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            mlistner = (onMultiChoiceListener) context;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString()+"onMultiChoiceListener must implemented");
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final ArrayList<String> selectedItemList = new ArrayList<>();

       // Intent i = new Intent(getContext(),MultipleChoiceDialogFragment.class);
     //   i.putStringArrayListExtra("arrayfinal",selectedItemList);

        AlertDialog.Builder mbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        final String[] list = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.selectableRole);
        mbuilder.setTitle("Chose Role").setMultiChoiceItems(list, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i, boolean b) {
                if (b){
                    selectedItemList.add(list[i]);

                }else {
                    selectedItemList.remove(list[i]);

                }


            }
        })
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                        mlistner.onPositiveButtonClicked(list, selectedItemList);

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        mlistner.onNegativeButtonClicked();

                    }
                });

        return mbuilder.create();


    }



}
```

i want use final list in another activity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android - Passing an Array of Classes Between Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31372513/android-passing-an-array-of-classes-between-activities)

Comment: Show us your `class` and give more infos; on which output you want.

Comment: You have to provide example code and scenario. You can pass custom class to Activity by implementing Parcellable but it may not fit your scenario.

Comment: this is my class